# Iterating through dictionary values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, finance, stock

I have 1000+ text files, each with two columns, one being dates, the other stock prices (at respective date). I have uploaded them and cast them into a dictionary using the following code:

```
filelist = os.listdir(r'insertfilepath')
filepath = r'insertfilepath'

dic1 = {}

for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath + file,sep='\t')
    dic1[file]= df
```

However, when I try to change the column names for each one using the following code:

```
for value in dic1:
    for df in value: 
        df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'Dates',df.columns[1]:'Prices'},inplace=True)
```

I get the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'rename'.

Interestingly this worked when I casted it to a list, but a I can't analyze the data in a list because I have no way of knowing which stock matches what data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to python so please go easy. Thanks

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for value in dic1` loops through the keys, which are file name strings in this case. You want `for value in dic1.values()`

If you want both keys and values, you use `dic1.items()` which returns (key, value) tuples

Comment: I wrote :for num in dic1.values():
    num.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'Dates',df.columns[1]:'Prices'}) ... still gave me the same error

Comment: It tells you that the values are strings still? Can you send the output from print(list(dic1.items())[:2])? This should have two tuples of key:value pairs

Comment: I actually just figured it out, now I have a new problem lol but I'll wait until tomorrow to post it if I cant figure it out. Thanks for your help on this, it was very valuable